API not accepting the new host and running with old host
In jmeter, I have changed the host but results are shown to be run with old host. pls suggest. api running fine in local postman.
In jmeter, I have changed the host but results are shown to be run with old host. pls suggest. api running fine in local postman.
this image shows the new host
this second image is the result which shows api ran with old host

You've changed the value of Host header in the HTTP Header Manager while you need to change "Server Name or IP" in the HTTP Request Sampler (or in HTTP Request Defaults)

